# populate CLLocation object from dictionary

Tags: objective-c, cllocation

I've tried many different ways and in every way I seem to be loosing some of the information that is already available on an existing Asset's location.

I'm creating a modified copy of an asset and would like to copy the location information available with that asset to it's modified copy. But the methods that are available in CLLocation do not have all the fields that are available for the existing Assets GPS. Here is what is available from existing asset:

```
       "{GPS}" =             {
            Altitude = "50.4666666666667";
            GPSVersion =                 (
                2,
                3,
                0,
                0
            );
            ImgDirection = "265.8132992327366";
            ImgDirectionRef = T;
            Latitude = "58.5314";
            LatitudeRef = N;
            Longitude = "21.5112";
            LongitudeRef = W;
            MapDatum = "WGS-84";
            Speed = "2.053334425692282";
            SpeedRef = K;
        };
```

The method with most option available under CLLocation is follows:

```
[loc initWithCoordinate:<#(CLLocationCoordinate2D)#> 
        altitude:<#(CLLocationDistance)#> 
        horizontalAccuracy:<#(CLLocationAccuracy)#> 
        verticalAccuracy:<#(CLLocationAccuracy)#> 
        course:<#(CLLocationDirection)#> 
        speed:<#(CLLocationSpeed)#> 
        timestamp:<#(nonnull NSDate *)#>];
```

I still seem to lose 'ImgDirectionRef' , 'LatitudeRef' , 'LongitudeRef' , 'MatDatum' , 'GPSVersion' with this method.

Does anyone know what else I can do to make sure that the CLLocation is exactly copied over to the modified asset. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to subclass `CLLocation` in order to store the extra values that are not part of `CLLocation`. e.g.

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@interface CustomLocation : CLLocation

@property NSInteger ImgDirectionRef;
//etc

@end
```

and then

```
CustomLocation *loc;
[loc initWithCoordinate:<#(CLLocationCoordinate2D)#> 
    altitude:<#(CLLocationDistance)#> 
    horizontalAccuracy:<#(CLLocationAccuracy)#> 
    verticalAccuracy:<#(CLLocationAccuracy)#> 
    course:<#(CLLocationDirection)#> 
    speed:<#(CLLocationSpeed)#> 
    timestamp:<#(nonnull NSDate *)#>];

loc.ImgDirectionRef = 123; // your value here
// set extra values here
```